# Twitter Bootstrap Grid Stacking Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Evening all,

I'm having a little trouble with the grid system and am looking fir a bit of guidance here. 
Take the following code for example:

```
    <div class="container">
           <div class="row"> <!-- PROBLEM -->

              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="problemclass">

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div> <!-- /PROBLEM -->
      </div> <!-- /container -->
  </header>
  <main>
      <div class="container">
          <!-- WORKS -->
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="notproblem"> 
                        {CONTENT}
                    </div>
                       etc...
```

As you can see, I've marked a row as PROBLEM in the header and it contains a 12 column span. The CSS for problem class is set at about 300px height and a background image (It is set at 300px because the background image is 300 px in height). the code looks like this:

```
.problemclass{
    height: 300px; 
    background: url('background.png'); 
}
```

Everything stacks and lays out perfectly... until I size the browser down to test the stacking. At this point, the row marked PROBLEM will begin to completely overlap the row marked WORKS; the content will overlap the background image, and the actual div goes under the background image! I have no freaking clue why LOL! My guess is that maybe I cannot have just a background with a set height and expect it to work?
Any advice would be appreciated, and I hope I was clear enough.

Also note that there are 2, 6 column grids above the 12 column grid in the same row that I did not include in attempt to keep the code a little more clean and clear.

Comment: what happens if you change height to max-height?

Comment: The image disappears completely. Maybe this indicates the container isn't big enough for the image?